# Fibonacci sequence property

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image: i want to know how to proove]
I think  its proof will be simple but. I dont know well
When the difference of number of sequence in fibonnaci is 1 or 2, i know how to prove but this is not

Answer (score 1):

$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a-b)$

$$\gcd(f_{n+3},f_n)=\gcd(f_{n+2}+f_{n+1},f_n)=\gcd(f_{n+1}+f_n+f_{n+1},f_n)=$$
$$=\gcd(2f_{n+1},f_n)$$
But $\gcd(f_{n+1},f_n)=1$

Then $$\gcd(f_{n+3},f_n)=\gcd(2f_{n+1},f_n)=$$
$0$ or $1$